# Can't read json in TemplateView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

abc.json:

```
{
  "employee": {
    "name": "Rose"

  }
}
```

views.py

```
class employee_ViewDetails_TemplateView(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'employee.djhtml'
      def get_data(self, **kwargs):
      json_data=json.loads(open(BASE_DIR+'/app/jsonRead/abc.json').read())
      context = {'ref':json_data},
      return render_to_response(request,self.template_name,context)
```

I am able to see the template is fully loaded but json is not able to load.
May be `render_to_response` is not the suitable method to render inside class based view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a `get_data` method in generic views. You probably meant [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    json_data=json.loads(open(BASE_DIR+'/app/jsonRead/abc.json').read())
    context = {'ref':json_data}
    return context
```

You also had an erroneous comma after the context and the `get_context_data` should only return the context.

Comment: Good catch for comma.